# Get rid of "Remote debugger is in a background tab" warning in React Native

Tags: react-native

I've started a new React Native project and I keep getting the following warning:

> Remote debugger is in a background tab which may cause apps to perform slowly. Fix this by foregrounding the tab (or opening it in a separate window).

It's a bit annoying so I wanna know how I can get rid of it? I'm running the debugger in Chrome and I moved it to a seperate window but it did not help.

Comment: For others reading this, I think what you need is a faster debugger instead of ignoring these warnings. Below answer by @varunvs to use react-native-debugger removes the warning and shortens your device output time

Comment: The correct answer ([below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54392003/656912)) is now simply to check the "Maintain Priority" checkbox on the debugger page.

Comment: since react-native v0.63.0 use `LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Remote debugger']);` from `react-native`

Answer (score 174, accepted):

If you have the *Maintain Priority* checkbox in the debugger window, try enabling it before you jump to any of the solutions below.

To get rid of the warning in your whole project add the following to your *outermost* Javascript file (most of the time that's `index.js` for React Native)

**for react-native** `v0.63+`**:**

Use `LogBox`:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging#logbox

```
LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Remote debugger']);
```

**for react-native** `v0.57 - v0.62`**:**

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Remote debugger']);
```

Reference this from the official React Native docs:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html

**react-native** `v0.56` **or below:**

Add the following early on in your code:

```
console.ignoredYellowBox = ['Remote debugger'];
```

Easy, simple and specific to that error. Works for me. Can substitute for any text you want.

Comment: Added this just before my AppRegistry.registerComponent statement and it worked! Thanks

Comment: I put this code in my top-level `index.js`. Works like a charm.
`if (__DEV__) {
  console.ignoredYellowBox = ['Remote debugger'];
}`

Comment: @MikeS. I got a warning `[eslint] '__DEV__' is not defined. (no-undef)`. Do you also get it?

Comment: @anticafe No, I don't get any warnings. So I'm not sure what the issue would be.

Comment: Hey I am using `YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Remote debugger', 'Require cycles']);` but both warnings are still appearing inside my console window. I am using 0.61.4 version of RN. Please help

Answer (score 47):

this solution is work for me

open/move http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui (default path for remote debugging) on the **separate window**

maybe that could help :)

Comment: just move the tab out of your normal group of 37 tabs into its own window. thanks

Comment: Yup, that works. But anyone can tell me why is that?

Comment: Think this is the correct answer as suggested in the warning message 'Remote debugger is in a background tab which may cause apps to perform slowly. Fix this by foregrounding the tab (or opening it in a separate window).'

Comment: This answer makes more sense instead of just adding more lines of code to avoid warning.

Answer (score 25):

You can use React Native Debugger available at https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger It is a standalone app for debugging React Native apps during development.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely will try it out but it's not exactly what I am looking for as an answer because it does not resolve the warning. I don't get the warning on other RN Apps on the same computer strangely

Comment: I had the similar issue but using React Native debugger solved it.

Comment: Thanks, I went for this solution as keeping the debugger in it's own windows doesn't erase the warning for me all the time

Comment: Installing another tool just to remove a warning is not the best solution, and that other tool has its own problems. The correct answer is kjonsson's one below - `console.ignoredYellowBox = ['Remote debugger'];
`

Comment: @this.lau_ Doesn't that just hide the warning and not fix the actual problem? I believe the problem we're trying to address is to fix the slow app performance while debugging. Forcibly hiding a warning will not fix it.

Comment: @varunvs, OP's question was "how to get rid of the warning", he didn't mention anything about performances (in my case I also don't mind about performances for development).

Answer (score 9):

1. Move `http://localhost:*****/debugger-ui` on the separate window.
2. Restart `Remote JS Debugging`.

Answer (score 8):

For me warning went away by **checking Maintain Priority Checkbox!**
[image: Maintain Priority Checkbox should be checked]

Answer (score 6):

It is because of number of tabs are opened in the browser with **React Native Remote Debugger UI tab**. I also faced the same issue.

To overcome this warning message you can use any one method from the following:

- Open an incognito tab then paste http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui on address bar and press **ENTER**. Finally reload the app **(Command+R)**.
- Close all the tabs in the browser. Keep only 1 tab opened then hit http://locahost:8081/debugger-ui then reload the app **(Command+R)**.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by @jakeforaker in one of the comment. The warning went away by simply opening the remote debugger in a separate window instead of a tab in your existing window of your browser (you have to reload your simulator though).

As the warning is saying keeping the remote debugger in the same window as other tabs

> may cause apps to perform slowly

So i think simply suppressing warning as mentioned by @kjonsson:- `console.ignoredYellowBox = ['Remote debugger'];` doesnt seem to be best solution.

Answer (score 6):

Since [this commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/5643bbc11d4fadfeec989327b63377f4a56d8c47) in March 2017, you can enable the **Maintain Priority** checkbox. When enabled, it **silently** plays a base64-encoded `.wav` file to prevent the debugger's browser tab from entering low-power mode, which can affect websocket performance. This will effectively prevent the warning you describe.

Answer (score 5):

This issue was resolved when I closed all open Chrome windows and started the Remove Debugging again. I had previously had open Chrome windows, so it 'seems' that having them open kills performance.

Answer (score 4):

I think the accepted answer is no longer accurate (at least for React Native v0.57+).

The correct code is now:

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Remote debugger']);
```

Reference this from the official React Native docs:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html

Comment: From my console: YellowBox has been replaced with LogBox. Please call LogBox.ignoreLogs() instead.  Things keep changing :)

Answer (score 3):

I am on Macbook. I fixed this issue by bringing the Debugger window on main desktop, rather than on having it on separate desktop which it thinks is in "Background".

[image]

Comment: i'm also facing the issue on mac, this solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue pop up yesterday.  Googling it led to this [Stack Overflow post](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10559#issuecomment-258704960).  In one of the response (by adriansprod), he suggested:

`Chrome debugger in it's own window fixes. But annoying problem`

It is likely that your React Native debugger is not in its own Chrome browser window but in a Chrome browser tab.  Pulling it out as its own window, as adriansprod suggest, fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

The (very annoying) error message is handled by [`debuggerWorker.js`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/local-cli/server/util/debuggerWorker.js#L25), which sadly doesn't include any configuration options to turn off the message. So for the time being there are no ways you can configure your application to disable the message.

The related code is outlined below ([original licence](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/LICENSE) applies):

```js
var visibilityState;
var showVisibilityWarning = (function() {
  var hasWarned = false;
  return function() {
    // Wait until `YellowBox` gets initialized before displaying the warning.
    if (hasWarned || console.warn.toString().includes('[native code]')) {
      return;
    }
    hasWarned = true;
    console.warn(
      'Remote debugger is in a background tab which may cause apps to ' +
      'perform slowly. Fix this by foregrounding the tab (or opening it in ' +
      'a separate window).'
    );
  };
})();
```

As you see, no configuration options are used, the whole thing is scoped off locally (see the above repo link for further details).

Answer (score 0):

I also have faced with same issue about one week ago and finally i have found solution that works excelent for me

It called reactotron, you can find it here - https://github.com/reactotron/reactotron and you can use it to:
* view your application state
* show API requests & responses
* perform quick performance benchmarks
* subscribe to parts of your application state
* display messages similar to console.log
* track global errors with source-mapped stack traces including saga stack traces!
* dispatch actions like a government-run mind control experiment
* hot swap your app's state
* track your sagas

I hope my post was helpful and you never will faced with this tedious warning .

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I use this in `index.js`

```
if (__DEV__) {
  console.ignoredYellowBox = [
    'Remote debugger',
    'Warning: isMounted… is deprecated',
    'Module RCTImageLoader'
  ];
}
```

Comment: I also imported `import { AppRegistry, YellowBox } from 'react-native';`

Comment: Although I just retested this in a new app and it doesn't seem to be working. Wonder if something changed in `0.57.4`?

Answer (score 0):

I had minimised the "http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/" window. Just opening it up (un minimising), and reloading the app removed the warning.

Answer (score 0):

there might be chances that Another debugger is already connected to packager.
so close your terminal and debugger google chrome.

if you are using visual studio's package manger then don't start package manager by Mac/other os terminal command.

so close all terminal and stop on going package manger and google chrome debugger.
start the process again.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Akshay Vijay Jain, mine went away by ticking this box!
[image]