# Unrecognized WebSocket connection option(s) `agent`, `perMessageDeflate`, `pfx`, `key`, `passphrase`... Did you mean to put these under `headers`?

Tags: react-native, websocket

Have you ever met this message in a React Native application using a WebSocket ( SocketIOClient from 'socket.io-client') ?...

```
Unrecognized WebSocket connection option(s) `agent`, `perMessageDeflate`, `pfx`, `key`, `passphrase`, `cert`, `ca`, `ciphers`, `rejectUnauthorized`. Did you mean to put these under `headers`?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one way to remove the error:

```
let socket = io.connect(SOCKET_URL, {
  timeout: 10000,
  jsonp: false,
  transports: [‘websocket’],
  autoConnect: false,
  agent: ‘-’,
  path: ‘/’, // Whatever your path is
  pfx: ‘-’,
  key: token, // Using token-based auth.
  passphrase: cookie, // Using cookie auth.
  cert: ‘-’,
  ca: ‘-’,
  ciphers: ‘-’,
  rejectUnauthorized: ‘-’,
  perMessageDeflate: ‘-’
});
```

Comment: pretty sure it only gets removed here is because you are not connected, once you call `.connect` its back

Answer (score 33):

Yes, this is happening in the WebSocket class constructor in Socket.io.  I think it happens when you specify your transport layer as 'websocket' in the constructor (which is necessary for React Native socket io use).  It doesn't do anything bad, but is annoying.
You can get rid of it with the react-native `YellowBox.ignoreWarnings`:
When initiating your app:

```
console.ignoredYellowBox = ['Remote debugger'];
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings([
    'Unrecognized WebSocket connection option(s) `agent`, `perMessageDeflate`, `pfx`, `key`, `passphrase`, `cert`, `ca`, `ciphers`, `rejectUnauthorized`. Did you mean to put these under `headers`?'
]);
```

Comment: I encountered this when upgrading to socket.io-client@2.2.0  Reverting back to 2.1.1 resolved it. https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/1254

Comment: So you are saying that it is just annoying noisy warning, but everything still works fine?

Comment: Yep.  Exactly. @Urasquirrel

Comment: Thanks so much! I was able to suppress the mobile screen warning with this! It still shows in my server logs. I will probably like to suppress this as well.

Comment: You mix old style(console.ignoredYellowBox) with new(YellowBox.ignoreWarnings), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43667194/4757986

Comment: Is there a way to silence this warning on the console as well?

Comment: @everydayproductive yes -> `console.disableYellowBox = true`

Comment: is this just a warning, if yes then why or if not , then any solution