# Socket IO keeps (re?)connecting, even after establishing a websocket

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to implement websockets. It manages to make a connection and prints `Backend, connected!` and `Frontend, connected!`, but when I type text into the input and press send, it just prints `Frontend, connected!` a bunch more times and nothing happens. What am I doing wrong here?

Here's what I have:

```
// server.js
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.use("/api/messages", require("./routes/api/messages"));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`));
```

```
// routes/api/messages.js
const express = require("express");

const router = express.Router();

const server = require("http").createServer();

const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  path: "/socket",
  serveClient: false,
  pingInterval: 10000,
  pingTimeout: 5000,
  cookie: false
});

io.on("connection", () => {
  console.log("Backend, connected!");
});

io.on("msg", function(msg) {
  console.log("entered!"); // <--- never prints!
  console.log("message: " + msg);
});

server.listen(5001);

router.post(...)

router.get(...)

module.exports = router;
```

And on my React Native front end, in one of my screens in React Navigation:

```
const Conversation = ({
  navigation,
  auth: { user },
  sendMessage
}) => {
  const [replyText, setReplyText] = useState("");

  const socket = io("http://192.168.112.110:5001", {
    path: "/socket",
    transports: ["websocket"],
    jsonp: false
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.connect();

    socket.on("connect", () => {
      console.log("Frontend, connected!");
    });

    socket.on("works?", () => {
      console.log("omg");
    });

    socket.on("connect_error", err => {
      console.log("error", err);
    });
  }, []);

  const handleSendReply = () => {
    if (validateLength(replyText) === 0) {
      setReplyTooShort(true);

      return;
    }

    sendMessage(
      replyText,
      user.username
    );

    console.log("replyText", replyText); // prints

    socket.emit("msg", replyText);

    setReplyText("");
  };

return <View>
        <Input
        label="reply"
        value={replyText}
        onChangeText={e => setReplyText(e)}
        />
        <View style={{ alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
        <Icon
            name="md-send"
            type="ionicon"
            iconStyle={{ paddingLeft: 20, paddingRight: 20, paddingTop: 10 }}
            onPress={() => handleSendReply()}
        />
        </View>
    </View>
}
```

"socket.io": "^2.3.0" // server

"socket.io-client": "^2.3.0" // client

---

Edit:

(The yellow warning should be ignored as per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53655887/2891356))

[image: img]

Comment: Can you also post a small image of the console?

Comment: Sure, I updated OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket server listens on connection event. 

When connection is successful a new socket object is created with a unique id.

This Socket object handles sending and receiving of events/data.

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => { 
  // console.log("Backend, connected!"); // user or client is connected.
  console.log("User connected with a unique socketId ", socket.id);
    socket.on("msg", function (msg) {
        console.log("entered!"); // <--- It will print now !
        console.log("message: " + msg);
    });

});
```

[Socket-io docs](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/#Introduction)

Comment: Ah, I see. It works now, but is there any way to get around [this](https://i.imgur.com/AD2mG3R.png)? It seems as though my `setReplyText` method forces the whole component to re-render and therefore create a new websocket connection.

Comment: @MikeK maybe handle socket connection separately only when page is refreshed?