# EXPO: Unable to resolve module ‘./debugger

Tags: react-native, debugging, expo

After a reload my app has stopped loading.
a
I have tried on both emulators and 2 real devives, android and ios.

The error is:

> Error: Unable to resolve module `./debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.d9da4ed7` from ``:

and occassionally I will get the error, 'unable to locate instance'.

I have tried the following:

1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all` .
2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` .
3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache` .
4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*` .
5. Restart the computer.

this is a bug i think

```
      Expo CLI 3.11.3 environment info:
        System:
          OS: macOS 10.15.2
          Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
        Binaries:
          Node: 12.8.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.8.0/bin/node
          Yarn: 1.19.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
          npm: 6.13.4 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.8.0/bin/npm
          Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
        IDEs:
          Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312
          Xcode: 11.2/11B41 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
        npmPackages:
          expo: ~36.0.0 => 36.0.2
          react: ~16.9.0 => 16.9.0
          react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz => 0.61.4
          react-navigation: ^4.0.10 => 4.0.10
        npmGlobalPackages:
          expo-cli: 3.11.3
```

Any ideas on what else I can try to resolve this?

The full error below:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module `./debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.d9da4ed7` from ``:

None of these files exist:
  * debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.d9da4ed7(.native|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json|.native.wasm|.wasm)
  * debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.d9da4ed7/index(.native|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json|.native.wasm|.wasm)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/serdarmustafa/task_location_namespace/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:163:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/serdarmustafa/task_location_namespace/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/serdarmustafa/task_location_namespace/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:282:16)
    at /Users/serdarmustafa/task_location_namespace/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:267:42
    at /Users/serdarmustafa/task_location_namespace/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1305:37
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/serdarmustafa/task_location_namespace/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:99:24)
    at _next (/Users/serdarmustafa/task_location_namespace/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:119:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
```

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` as well?

Comment: I had another error about the navigation module being moved. When I fixed that your error went away.

Comment: I have the same error. Is there a way to fix it without downgrading npm?

Answer (score 43):

I solved this error by stopping the debugger `cmd + d` && `Stop debugging` then doing a hard reload on the open debugger tab in chrome `alt + control + click on reload button` and choose `Empty cache and hard reload` then restart debugger.

Comment: Thank you so much @chaim

Comment: The solution works partially, the debugger starts working, but the error in console didn't disappear. Anyway, that solution helped to continue working. Thank you!

Comment: Same for me Chaki. No error but the issue with missing module is gone. At least...

Comment: For those confused that `alt + control + click on reload button`, this only works if you have the inspector open, with `cmd + alt + i` (though for me, doing a hard cache reload didn't fix the issue)

Comment: Tried the same but not work

Answer (score 9):

I just had the same issue and I tried all the answer above, for some strange reasons none worked for me. But here is what worked for me.
 - Delete the `package-lock.json` and/or `yarn-lock.json`
 - run `npm i`

it worked like magic. it worked for me, it might not work for you but at least give it  try. #cheers

Comment: This + a hard cache reset worked for me. I suspect it has to do with mixing package managers, as the bug happened right after I used Yarn for one of the packages after only using NPM.

Answer (score 6):

Solved it for me in two ways:

First I simply removed the `sourceMappingURL` from the mentioned files,
as these seemed to raise the error (build problems?).

But as I had to redo this on any package update / addition (which got quite annoying, as you might have guessed ; ), I was quite happy that `@react-native-community/cli-debugger-ui` `v4.7.0` has been released yesterday!
So I quickly added the following to my `package.json`:

```
"resolutions": {
    "@react-native-community/cli-debugger-ui": "4.7.0"
  }
```

Now, after deleting `yarn.lock`, running `npx react-native-clean-project` (the same could have been accomplished by deleting `node_modules`, cleaning the individual builds & pods, but `react-native-clean-project` is so much neater % ) & running `yarn` again, the problem was gone.

(Be sure to remove the resolution, when RN updates again...)

Reference: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/1081#issuecomment-614223917

Comment: nice share `npx react-native-clean-project`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This can also happen if you moved your code modules into another directory like `/src` in order to take advantage of absolute path imports by using the `module-resolver` plugin in `babel.config`

Comment: thanks for the answer, so how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, nothing worked at all.

How I managed to fix it:

I started a new fresh project in another folder using Expo Fully Managed workflow.

```
npx create-expo-app my-app && cd my-app
```

Then `expo start`

After starting a fresh project with less boilerplate, the app ran on my Expo GO app, and then I shook the phone to pull up Expo Menu, Clicked Stop Debug Remote JS.

This was how I stopped it, and I opened the initial project and discovered it was gone too.

This hack is for you if you have tried everything and nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

found here: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/1081#issuecomment-1025055453

- manually uninstall the app
- `npm run start --reset-cache`

done !

Answer (score 0):

I resovled this error by removing node modules + yarn.lock in project

Answer (score 0):

In my case ,I have updated react-native verison and the debugger broke.

Run `npm i react-devtools-core` in order to update debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, press 'ctrl-m' have no response, so I go to the "Android virtual device" and wipe out all data of my current device and re-loading everything again. It work!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have also the same probleme this is whath I did

You have two way

try running `npm start -- --reset-cache` so that the bundler is cache is reset

or click `reload` from the chrome debugger window, which reloads the app in debugger mode on the simulator for you

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the Expo application, and the problem disappeared. Maybe it will help someone, too.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the **Maintain Priority** checkbox in the browser's debugger tab as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146446/get-rid-of-remote-debugger-is-in-a-background-tab-warning-in-react-native) because I was looking for a way to get rid of the **Remote debugger is in a background tab** warning. Once I reloaded, no more **Remote debugger** warning and no more **unable to resolve module debugger** warning.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth: When using a Development Build, ensure the app on the device has the most recent build, with the native modules included.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to import react in one of functional component and started getting this issue.

```
import React from 'react'
```

After adding it issue resolved.

Answer (score -1):

This can also be caused if you install a dependency, but forget to install other dependencies needed for that dependency. For example, I installed react-native-push-notification, but forgot to install PushNotificationIOS, and I got an identical error.